# Javascript Error: missing = in destructuring declaration

Tags: javascript, emacs, js2-mode

I am getting a javascript error

> "missing = in destructuring declaration"

What could be the problem?

Comment: Can you post code at all?  Do you have a line number and a snippet you could show us?

Comment: Are you using http://code.google.com/p/js2-mode/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a standard javascript error. It's coming from your editor. You must be using the [js2-mode](http://code.google.com/p/js2-mode/) (Javascript mode) for your Emacs editor. This could be a missing equals in for loop. Example:

```
for(i 0; i < arr.length;i++); /* missing = in destructuring declaration */
```

However, without looking at your code, we can only guess.

Answer (score 0):

I got that error with a bad assignation (Python style) :
var x,y = 2,3 ;
instead of :
var x = 2, y = 3;

Comment: The accepted answer already stated that it's only guesswork what the actual problem is, without any code provided. This should be a comment at best.